# Hibernate doesn't fill second table when one-to-one mapping is performed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

I have small application which is responsible for saving data in database. I'm using `Hibernate` for this purpose. Below is my code:

**User class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
@Transactional
public class User implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "USER_ID")
private int userId;

@Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "SURNAME")
private String surname;

@Column(name = "AGE")
private int age;

@Column(name = "EMAIL")
private String email;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Address address;

public User() {

}

public User(String firstName, String secondName, int age, String email) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.surname = secondName;
    this.age = age;
    this.email = email;
}

// GETTERS/SETTERS
```

**Address class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
@Transactional
public class Address implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign", parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "user"))
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
@Column(name = "USER_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
private int addressId;

@Column(name = "STREET")
private String street;

@Column(name = "STREET_NUMBER")
private String streetNumber;

@Column(name = "FLAT_NUMBER")
private String flatNumber;

@Column(name = "POSTAL_CODE")
private String postalCode;

@Column(name = "CITY")
private String city;

@Column(name = "COUNTRY")
private String country;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
private User user;


public Address() {

}

public Address(String street, String streetNumber, String flatNumber, String postalCode, String city, String country) {
    this.street = street;
    this.streetNumber = streetNumber;
    this.flatNumber = flatNumber;
    this.postalCode = postalCode;
    this.city = city;
    this.country = country;
}

//GETTERS/SETTERS
```

And when I perform `save()` method which is responsible for saving data in this two tables only users table is filled up.

I found this solution [Hibernate @OneToOne with Shared Primary Key(bidirectional). Dependent entity not persisted in DB.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41629976/hibernate-onetoone-with-shared-primary-keybidirectional-dependent-entity-not)

but it doesn't work for me.

I'm using:

- Hibernate 4.3.6.Final
- Spring 4.3.6.RELEASE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Address class should be coded as follows (assuming that Address should be created with the same Id as the User where the id is generated):

```
@Id
@Column(name = "USER_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
private int addressId;


@MapsId
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "USER_ID")
private User user;
```

**During Persist**

```
User u = new User();
// populate u fields

Address a = new Address();
a.setUser(u);
// populate a fields

session.persist(a);
```

Comment: Great. Glad i could help